# Reemplazar múltiples carácteres

Tags: nodejs

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, hace poco hice un filtro de palabras ofensivas que usaba RegExp, sin embargo, para que el filtro fuese más efectivo, añadí un leet2string:

```
const leet2string = {
  "4": "a",  "@": "a",  "^": "a",  "α": "a",
  "λ": "a",  "8": "b",  "ß": "b",  "(": "c",
  "[": "c",  "{": "c",  "<": "c",  "3": "e",
  "6": "g",  "9": "g",  "!": "i",  "1": "i",
  "|": "i",  "0": "o",  "5": "s",  "$": "s",
  "§": "s",  "7": "t",  "+": "t",  "†": "t"
}

let out = "";

for(const char of input) {
  if(!leet2string[char]) out += char.toLowerCase();
  else out += leet2string[char];
}
```

Sin embargo, hay ciertos caracteres "leet" como `][` (i) que representan ciertos carácteres en múltiples letras (y que, por lo tanto, el fragmento de código de arriba no puede convertirlo adecuadamente).

Por ejemplo, en el paquete [`leetscript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leetscript) hay un leet2string que básicamente convierte `lorem ipsum` en `|_023|V| ][95[_]]V[`.

En el código fuente del paquete leetscript están los carácteres que se pueden usar: [`lib/leetscript.js#L10-L41`](https://github.com/kevingimbel/leetscript/blob/master/lib/leetscript.js#L10-L41). ¿Cómo puedo revertirlo? Había pensado en una cadena de `.replace()`, ya que puede reemplazar varias letras en otras, pero no sé si es la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Gracias por adelantado.